# Where can I get/set the application id?

Tags: install4j

I need to get the `ApplicationRegistry.ApplicationInfo` for an installed application during an update installation. Background therefore: the application should be updated from 32bit up to 64bit and I want to load the response file from the previous installation. Now I tried to get the `ApplicationInfo` with a script and wanted to set the installation directory to load the response file with the corresponding action. Now I don't know what the parameter for the application id `getApplicationInfoById(java.lang.String id)` stands for. Is it the media file id or the id of the launcher? For both I do not get any `ApplicationInfo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter of `getApplicationInfoById` is the application ID. The returned values include installations in the 32-bit and the 64-bit subsystems if called from a 64-bit installer.

Comment: I missed to get the right value for the _applicationId_. Intead of using the predefined compiler variable "_sys.applicationId_" I tried the launcher id and that was the missunderstanding. Now the registry find the right installations and we can load the response file from this location.